# Buddypress multisite with shared users but segregated groups, activity, forums

Tags: buddypress

I have this project to create a multi-site Wordpress + Buddypress network.

Users table should be shared and common to all sites in the network (same user profile for all sites in the network) but each site should have its own activity flow, groups and forums.

Any ideas? Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

The Buddypress Multi-Network plugin is probably what you're looking for. You can create multiple social networks on a single Buddypress install.

[Buddypress Multi-Network Plugin](http://buddydev.com/buddypress/introducing-buddypress-multi-network-plugin-create-multiple-separate-social-networks-on-a-single-buddypress-install/)

Answer (score 0):

Newer versions of BuddyPress has this feature already build in, you don't need any other plugins, just need to paste this line in wp-config.php file

```
define( 'BP_ENABLE_MULTIBLOG', true );
```

you can also create a file named **bp-custom.php** in plugin folder, and paste that line there if you don't want to change wp-config.php file